# Does the category of integral domains admit a symmetric monoidal structure?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathbf{Int}$ be the category of integral domains with injective homomorphisms. Does it admit a symmetric monoidal structure? If so, can we choose $\mathbb{Z}$ as the unit object? If it helps to answer the question, we can also work in the category of (finitely generated) algebras over a field $K$ which are integral domains.

The "obvious" constructions (tensor product of rings, polynomial ring over the product of underlying sets, just take the first ring) are either not well-defined or not associative. The category also has no products or coproducts.

I am inclined to believe that there is no symmetric monoidal structure, but I bet this must be hard to prove if it is true. I have asked this question some years ago at [SE/1233631](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233631/functorial-construction-with-two-integral-domains), but didn't get the answer.

Comment: Here's a start: the monoidal unit $I$ will need to have trivial endomorphism monoid (like $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ do). The reason is that the symmetric monoidal structure induces an injective homomorphism from $\mathrm{End}(I)$ to the centre of the category, and this centre is trivial.

Comment: To see this, let $t$ be any natural endomorphism of the identity functor and consider naturality against any homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to R$ for any object $R$. This shows that $t_R : R \to R$ must be of the form $r \mapsto p(r)$ for a fixed polynomial $p$ that is independent of $R$. But then already for $R = \mathbb{Z}$, the only polynomial $p$ for which $r \mapsto p(r)$ is a homomorphism is $p = x$. This shows that the identity transformation is the only natural endomorphism of the identity functor.

Comment: (Actually my comments assume *all* homomorphisms to be morphisms, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is no, say over an integral domain $K$ not admitting all roots of unity, if $K$ is the unit of the tensor product $\odot$.

Indeed, fix any $n$ such that $K$ does not admit an $n$th root of unity and consider $i:K\to K(\zeta_n)$.

By functoriality, for any automorphism $\sigma$ of $K(\zeta_n)$, we get an automorphism $id\odot \sigma$ of $K(\zeta_n) \odot K(\zeta_n)$. Furthermore, $(id\odot \sigma)\circ (i\odot id) = i\odot \sigma = (i\odot id)\circ (id_K\odot \sigma)$ as maps $K(\zeta_n)\to K(\zeta_n)\odot K(\zeta_n)$.

It follows that $id\odot \sigma$ acts *nontrivially* on the $n$th roots of unity, as soon as $\sigma$ does.

On the other hand, $(id\odot \sigma)\circ (id\odot i)= (id\odot i) $ as maps $K(\zeta_n)\to K(\zeta_n)\odot K(\zeta_n)$, and so $id\odot \sigma$ acts trivially on the $n$th roots of unity. This is a contradicton.

Note that this argument fails for $\odot = \otimes$ because $K(\zeta_n)\otimes K(\zeta_n)$ is no longer integral, and in particular there can be too many $n$th roots of unity: $i\odot id$ and $id\odot i$ hit a different set of roots of unity. In the case of $\odot$, because $K(\zeta_n)\odot K(\zeta_n)$ is assumed to be integral, we know that both $i\odot id$ and $id\odot i$ hit exactly all the $n$th roots of unity.

One can replace roots of unity by "roots of some polynomial" with the same line of reasoning, so this argument works as soon as $K$ is not algebraically closed. Probably there is none also if $K$ is algebraically closed, but the proof would have to be a bit different.

Comment: Do you assume that $K$ is the unit?

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the proof. Can you please add more details in the statements that $id \odot \sigma$ acts non-trivially resp. trivially on the roots of unity? Also, roots of unity in which rings?

Comment: I think so, otherwise I cannot get a map $K(\zeta_n)\to K(\zeta_n)\odot K(\zeta_n)$, only $K(\zeta_n)\odot K \to K(\zeta_n)\odot K(\zeta_n)$, and I have little control over the source. But somehow you only need to assume "the unit is not algebraically closed".

Comment: For your second comment: the key point here is that it does not matter in which ring, which is where I use integrality - any integral domain has at most $n$ $n$th roots of unity, and so if I have an injective map of integral domains $R\to S$ where $R$ has all $n$th roots of unity, then they are also all the ones that are in $S$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why the automorphism acts non-trivially on the roots of unity.

Comment: So the first part of the argument shows that it is compatible with the automorphism $\sigma$ on $K(\zeta_n)$, which acts nontrivially on roots of unity - but they have the same roots of unity !

Comment: The second part of the argument shows that it is compatible with the identity automorphism of $K(\zeta_n)$, which acts trivially on the roots of unity - but again, they have the same roots of unity  regardless of the specific choice of embedding